# Taking information by line from a file to tuple

Tags: python, file, tuples

I'm doing a python decryting program for a school project.
So first of all, i have a function who takes a file as argument. Then i must take all the line by line and return a tuple.
This file containt 3 things : -a number(whatever it's), -the decrypted text, -the crypted text)

```
import sys
fileName = sys.argv[-1]


def load_data(fileName):
    tuple = ()
    data = open(fileName, 'r')
    content = data.readlines()
    for i in contenu:
        tuple += (i,)
    return tuple            #does nothing why?
    print(tuple)

load_data(fileName)
```

Output:

```
('13\n', 'mecanisme chiffres substituer\n', "'dmnucmnn gmnuaetiihmnunofrutfrmhamprmnunshusfua f ludmuaoccsfta rtofumruvosnu vmzul ur aemudmulmnudmaetiihmhulmnucmnn gmnuaetiihmnunofrudtnpoftblmnunosnul uiohcmudusfurmxrmuaofnrtrsmudmulmrrhmnuctfsnaslmnun fnu aamfrumrudmua h armhmnubl fanuvosnun vmzuqsmulmucma ftncmudmuaetiihmcmfrusrtltnmuaofntnrmu unsbnrtrsmhulmnua h armhmnudsucmnn gmudmudmp hrup hudu srhmnumfuhmnpmar frusfudtartoff thmudmuaetiihmcmfr'")
```

Output needed:

```
(13,'mecanisme chiffres substituer','dmnucmnn gmnuaetiihmnunofrutfrmhamprmnunshusfua f ludmuaoccsfta rtofumruvosnu vmzul ur aemudmulmnudmaetiihmhulmnucmnn gmnuaetiihmnunofrudtnpoftblmnunosnul uiohcmudusfurmxrmuaofnrtrsmudmulmrrhmnuctfsnaslmnun fnu aamfrumrudmua h armhmnubl fanuvosnun vmzuqsmulmucma ftncmudmuaetiihmcmfrusrtltnmuaofntnrmu unsbnrtrsmhulmnua h armhmnudsucmnn gmudmudmp hrup hudu srhmnumfuhmnpmar frusfudtartoff thmudmuaetiihmcmfr')
```

The tuple need to be like this (count,word_list,crypted), 13 as count and so on..

If someone can help me it would be great.
Sorry if i'm asking wrongly my question..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this to avoid the '\n' characters at the end

```
import sys
fileName = sys.argv[-1]
def load_data(fileName):
    tuple = ()
    data = open(fileName, 'r')
    content = data.readlines()
    for i in content:
        tuple += (i.strip(''' \n'"'''),)
    return tuple

print(load_data(fileName));
```

Note that a function ends when ever it finds a return statement, if you want to print the value of tuple do the before return statement or print the returned value.

Comment: Thank's but i'v a problem with the last one has " ' ...' " . And i only need the '...'

Comment: So do i need to take one by one and put it in a variable and then create the tuple?

Comment: I edited the answer, please check if it helps. you could strip for specific characters as i did in tuple += (i.strip(''' \n'"'''),)

Comment: Yea it'worked but, the first one was an integer inside de file, and i must keep it as an integer not a string..

Comment: Sorry i've juste realized that, the first one is an integer, the second one, a list, and the last one a string

Comment: In that case convert it into that format using int() or list() functions accordingly

Answer (score 0):

I am a little confused about what the file in question looks like, but from what I could infer from the output you got the file appears to be something like this:

some number

decrypted text

encrypted text

If so, the most straightforward way to do this would be

```
with open('lines.txt','r') as f:
    all_the_text = f.read() 
    list_of_text = all_the_text.split('\n') 
    tuple_of_text = tuple(list_of_text)
    print(tuple_of_text)
```

Explanation:
The `open` built-in function creates an object that allows you to interact with the file. We use `open` with the argument `'r'` to let it know we only want to read from the file. Doing this within a with statement ensures that the file gets closed properly when you are done with it. The `as` keyword followed by `f` tells us that we want the file object to be placed into the variable f. f.read() reads in all of the text in the file. String objects in python contain a `split` method that will place strings separated by some delimiter into a list *without* placing the delimiter into the separated strings. The `split` method will return the results in a list. To put it into a tuple, simply pass the list into `tuple`.

Comment: Thank's a lot for your reply, i did not have seen your answer and i'm happy to see that i've a code same as yours ;) Have a good day